# Docker Swarm: no suitable node (max replicas per node limit exceed) why?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have this dockr-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: ${MONGO_USERNAME}
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MONGO_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

  node-app:
    depends_on:
      - mongo
    image: USERNAME/PRIVATE_REPO_NAME:0.1
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      placement:
        max_replicas_per_node: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.25'
          memory: 256M

  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - node-app
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306
      - 33060:33060
    volumes:
      - mysql-db:/var/lib/mysql

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on: 
      - mysql

  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./portainer-data:/data
    ports:
      - 9000:9000

  volumes:
    mongo-db:
    mysql-db:
```

and docker-compose-prod.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  node-app:
    build:
      context: .
      target: production
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    command: npm start
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14 as base

FROM base as production
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install --only=production
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4000

FROM base as development
....
```

Nginx default.conf

```
server { # simple reverse-proxy
  listen       80;

  # pass requests for dynamic content to rails/turbogears/zope, et al
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://node-app:4000;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

I build the image and push it to the **private docker repo** then on the VPS (1 vCPU and 1 GM RAM) I pull the image then run

```
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml -c docker-compose-prod.yml nodestack --with-registry-auth
```

But I run `docker stack ps nodestack` I get

```
is7hybeurfgb   nodestack_adminer.1     adminer:latest                  docker-desktop   Running         Running about a minute ago
l92hsxrnpznh   nodestack_mongo.1       mongo:latest                    docker-desktop   Running         Preparing about a minute ago
2sg4x4lzk5uy   nodestack_mysql.1       mysql:latest                    docker-desktop   Running         Running 2 minutes ago
88vnttgk5grb   nodestack_nginx.1       nginx:stable-alpine             docker-desktop   Running         Running 2 minutes ago
7l5bm8tnjatv   nodestack_node-app.1    USERNAME/PRIVATE_REPO_NAME:0.1   docker-desktop   Running         Running 2 minutes ago
4xn3odusd265   nodestack_node-app.2    USERNAME/PRIVATE_REPO_NAME:0.1                    Running         Pending 2 minutes ago          "no suitable node (max replica…"
o38en2hwnikp   nodestack_portainer.1   portainer/portainer-ce:latest   docker-desktop   Running         Running about a minute ago
```

and it doesn't recreate the nodes with the new updates.
Why do I get `no suitable node (max replicas per node limit exceed)` and how to fix it to keep running 2 replicas with only 1 node in each one?

Comment: How many nodes are in your swarm cluster? Docker doesn't create new nodes for you.

Comment: @BMitch hope you can help me identify that. I just started learning Docker but couldn't find a solution for this issue.

Comment: 1 Mongo + 1 Adminer + 1 MySQL + 1 Nginx + 1 Portainer and supposed to run 2 replicas of NodeJS each one contains 1 node)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confusing a node in a swarm cluster with a NodeJS instance in a container. They have nothing to do with each other. From this output:

```
7l5bm8tnjatv   nodestack_node-app.1    USERNAME/PRIVATE_REPO_NAME:0.1   docker-desktop   Running         Running 2 minutes ago
4xn3odusd265   nodestack_node-app.2    USERNAME/PRIVATE_REPO_NAME:0.1                    Running         Pending 2 minutes ago          "no suitable node (max replica…"
```

It looks like you're running on `docker-desktop`, with a single node swarm cluster. You'll see that in `docker node ls`. To deploy multiple containers on your desktop, remove the constraint:

```
        max_replicas_per_node: 1
```

Or setup a cluster of multiple swarm nodes (VMs) and deploy to that cluster.

Comment: I'm building on my machine running Docker desktop but deploying on VPS not locally

Comment: When I remove ` max_replicas_per_node` and deploy the stack, there's downtime. I want to use replicas with a single node in each to prevent downtime

Comment: when I run `docker node ls` on the server I get only 1 record with HOSTNAME `docker` so how is it possible to create 2 replicas with a single node in each correctly?

Comment: It's not clear you're in a VPS when the node name is `docker-desktop`. `max_replicas_per_node` doesn't impact the number of concurrent replicas in the cluster, it affects the number of replicas you can run on the node. If you want to prevent downtime, look at healthchecks and the `update_config` options. https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#update_config

Comment: docker-desktop is locally where I build but I deploy on the VPS. Thanks for your help so far I really appreciate it.